# service broker catalog views - permissions required to query

Tags: sql, permissions, view, catalog

I have discovered that querying catalog views (e.g. sys.conversation_endpoints) under my non-sa/restricted user will succeed but always return an empty set.

What permission(s) do I need to grant my SQL login to be able to successfully query service broker catalog views..?

Thanks in advance,

Tamim.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to grant VIEW DEFINITION:

GRANT VIEW Definition TO MyCrippledUser

turned out nice,